# Filter an array from another array

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array:

```
self.helpers = [
       { name: ' abc ', helper: ' my helper text1 ' },
       { name: ' def ', helper: ' my helper text2 ' },
       { name: ' xyz ', helper: ' my helper text3 ' }
];
```

If I have a single string `var testdata = 'abc'`, I can use `ko.utils.arrayFilter` to get a json array with objects from `self.helpers` where `name` equals `'abc'`.

But what do I do to filter `self.helpers` if I have a string array: `testdata=[' abc ',' def ']`?

I should get the result as below:

```
[{ name: ' abc ', helper: ' my helper text1 ' },
 { name: ' def ', helper: ' my helper text2 ' }];
```

Does knockoutjs have anything similar to `IN` from sql? jQuery has `in_array` but how do I use it in this case, and moreover: is it the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for special Knockout (or jQuery) code, this can be *easily* done with vanilla Javascript. Here's my suggestion, using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var helpers = [
   { name: ' abc ', helper: ' my helper text1 ' },
   { name: ' def ', helper: ' my helper text2 ' },
   { name: ' xyz ', helper: ' my helper text3 ' }
];

var testdata = [' abc ',' def '];

var result = helpers.filter(function(h) {
  return testdata.indexOf(h.name) >= 0;
});

// for demo:
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="x"></pre>
```

Incidentally, [jQuery's `inArray` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/7103d8ef47e04a4cf373abee0e8bfa9062fd616f/src/core.js#L328) uses the same thing in its implementation, which currently boils down to:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    return arr == null ? -1 : indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
}
```